# What should be done when an answer has become obsolete?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[Using Google Maps as layer in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/can-i-use-google-maps-as-a-layer-in-arcmap) came to the front page today, and the accepted answer is obsolete. The linked software no longer enables a google maps layer in Arcmap.

What should be done in such a situation? Can we close it or mark it as obsolete?

Comment: Create a new question with the link to the old answer in the question.

Comment: Looking at the question, maybe we should also be asking ourselves how to handle answers that provide ways to circumvent ToS, licensing or other instruments that protect intellectual property.  In other words "How do I do X?" may not be a bad question.  But if some answers or comments claim that "Doing X is illegal", while other answers show "here's how you do X".  How should we handle this?  I bet this issue has come up on SO.

Comment: @kirk I think circumvention is a related but separate question (and a good discussion to have).

Answer (score 6):

It just needs an obsolete tag/flag that's front and center, and maybe a comment why it's obsolete.  Even obsolete questions have good answers.

Comment: A question can have an obsolete tag, but an answer cannot. What if the question is relevant and it's just the highest-rated or accepted answer that is obsolete?

Comment: Right, I hadn't looked at the question closely enough.  Would the easiest way be to just edit the answer with OBSOLETE right at the beginning and a (reason) in parentheses.

Comment: yes, editing the accepted answer is what I would do, and likely downvote as well, depending on just how much right/wrong info is in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

On Meta Stack Exchange there is a feature request that I made which I think would help in this situation: [Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/keeping-special-status-for-accepted-answers-without-sticking-them-to-top-forever)

It proposes that the Accept status should age away without loss of awarded points, and remain renewable by the question asker.

Comment: Seems like a good proposal..I've voted for it